# Winword using one core 100 %

Tags: windows, windows-vista, microsoft-office-2003

Randonmly we have an on some computers an svchost-process that hosts windoword.exe (2003) and some other apps amd consumes 100percent of a processor core, even if word or outlook never has been started.

The fact that this process exists seems to be ok, but it's unclear why it reacts like this. It could be corrected if outlook will be configured not to take word as editor and the restart the computer and reenabling word as editor. But the question is why this happens.

The configuration is vista32 and office 2003sp3

Is this a known issue?

Comment: The problem might be because WinWord is opening an extremely large document.

Comment: Does winword also open files if it runs in the background as outlook-editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Winword set as your email editor in Outlook, then Winword will run in the background, and can often stay running in the background after you exit Outlook.

Some common situations that can cause Winword to eat up 100% processor, are large files, extra complex files, formatted emails from odd email clients (if using Word as email editor), and printing (either because of a bad driver version, or for any of the reasons above).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's winword never runs as a service.

winword.exe is actually mentioned as a virus, with removal instructions [here](http://www.spywareremove.com/removewinwordexe.html).
(Do not delete Microsoft's winword by mistake.)

I would also suggest some antivirus scans by well-known products.
Do not be misled by all these fake antivirus products now floating around.

Comment: We have a permament active AV and all OS-and Application-patches were installed as they come out. Outlook uses word as editor and that's why it is started in am svchost at boot time. This seems to be ok, because I read an article at support.microsoft.com stating this. 
The question is, why it consumes such a amount of resources.

Comment: SpywareRemove hosts "fake antivirus products".

Comment: @happy clicker: Never used it, but I believe winword should only be running when Outlook is running, and not as a service. Using an AV doesn't guarantee not being infected. Which AV are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen winword run as a service on any of our machines and Word is the default editor for all our Outlook clients.